# Bash output is not putting the inputs in the correct spot

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This is my file for reading lines from input.txt and printing them out.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter an apartment number:" aptNumber
while IFS=$' \n' read -r firstName lastName leaseStart leaseEnd balance;
do
echo "Apartment Number: $aptNumber"
echo "Tenant Name: $lastName,$firstName"
echo "Lease Start: $leaseStart"
echo "Lease End: $leaseEnd"
echo "Current Balance: $balance"
done < input.txt
```

input.txt

```
John Doe
07/07/19 07/07/20
900
```

This is the output it's giving me

```
Enter an apartment number:001
Apartment Number: 001
Tenant Name: Doe,John
Lease Start:
Lease End:
Current Balance:
Apartment Number: 001
Tenant Name: 07/07/20,07/07/19
Lease Start:
Lease End:
Current Balance:
Apartment Number: 001
Tenant Name: ,900
Lease Start:
Lease End:
Current Balance:
```

This is the output i need

```
Apartment Number: 001
Tenant Name: Doe,John
Lease Start: 07/07/19
Lease End: 07/07/20
Current Balance: 900
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Shouldn't the IFS be set to take a new variable after every space and newline?

Comment: @ReidBoulet `read` reads a single line, then splits the result based on `$IFS`. Changing `$IFS` affects the splitting step, but not the read-a-single-line step. If you want to change the read-a-single-line step, you need to use the `-d` ("delimiter") option to change what it uses as an end-of-line delimiter.

Comment: From the bash man-page, about IFS: _The  Internal  Field Separator that is ... to split **lines into  words  with  the  read  builtin**  command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest with `bash`:

```
read -r -p "Enter an apartment number:" aptNumber
while read -r first last; do
  read -r start end
  read -r balance
  echo "Apartment Number: $aptNumber"
  echo "Tenant Name: $last,$first"
  echo "Lease Start: $start"
  echo "Lease End: $end"
  echo "Current Balance: $balance"
done < input.txt
```

Every `read` in this loop reads one line of `input.txt`.

Output:

```
Enter an apartment number:42
Apartment Number: 42
Tenant Name: Doe,John
Lease Start: 07/07/19
Lease End: 07/07/20
Current Balance: 900
```

---

See `help read` for read's options.